# Can I send messages via Facebook App without installing Facebook Messenger?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, facebook-messenger

When I want to send a chat message via Facebook App it forces me to install Facebook Messenger. Is there any way to pass it except chatting via Internet browser? Android 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich

Answer (score 1):

**No**, unfortunately.

To chat, you need to install the facebook messenger application. You can send offline messages (facebook mail) with the facebook app.

Not really a solution: But without either the messenger app or the facebook app on my phone, I find that I tend to use my free time a lot better than constantly reading updates on my social networking applications. The important people in my life have my mobile number and can contact me in case of an emergency. Try it. You will appreciate the simple things in life more.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried disabling my Facebook Messenger and sent a message via the Facebook app successfully. Turns out you don't really need the messenger to send messages. Its just there so that chat heads will be available when you send a message. And oh, it does not search for the messenger app.

Im on Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **for now**.

Facebook is rumored to be removing messaging capabilities from the main Facebook app in a ploy to get more users to download their Messenger app.

To send messages without Messenger, you can simply uninstall it and use the Facebook app. The middle tab (third from the right or left) is devoted to messaging.

Tested on my Galaxy S5 running KitKat.

Comment: Well, taken literally you've answered the "is there any" part as yes/no question. But I guess the OP was interested in a "how" – as what good does it do to know "it is possible" when you can't use it? ;) Maybe you could [edit] your post and include the "how-to" part as well? Thanks!